# Outlook 2007 Removing Reminders on Shared Calendars

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Is there a way to remove the automatic reminders on a shared calendar without having to manually enter it in for each appointment, while keeping the automatic reminders for a non-shared calendar?  Ex. My Calendar I want the reminders for my appointments - Shared Events Calendar, no reminders.

Comment: If you're talking about two different calendars, then you can change the settings for each of them individually, including default reminders.  If you're talking about a single calendar, which you use yourself but also share, then I don't think you can do what you're asking.